# Is it possible to use a Cloudflare TLS certficate for an internal website that is not on the Internet?

Tags: ssl, cloudflare

Is it possible to use a Cloudflare generated TLS certficate for an internal website that is not available over the Internet?  So any user within the internal network would not receive certificate errors when visiting that website.

When I search for this, I get Cloudflare results that are confusing.

From what I've always been aware of, an internal CA certificate would need to be set up.  You can then generate and sign certificates for internal websites.  Users would need to trust the CA's certificate so they don't get errors.  In the case of a Windows CA/domain, users that are on that domain would not receive certificate errors.

Comment: User (client) _systems or programs_ must trust an internal CA, but one of the features of domain-joined Windows is that the DC can 'push' this cert to user machine stores automatically without the users doing anything; such a cert is trusted by IE, Edge, Chrome, dotnet, and much other software, but _not_ Firefox (which has its own private truststore).

Answer (score 1):

I'm  not sure what kind of certificate you mean. If you refer to Cloudflare Origin CA certificates: these are [clearly not usable for this purpose](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000479507-Managing-Cloudflare-Origin-CA-certificates):

> Origin CA certificates only encrypt traffic between Cloudflare and your origin web server and are **not trusted by client browsers when directly accessing your origin website outside of Cloudflare**.

If you refer to the  certificates seen by clients when accessing a site protected by Cloudflare: these cannot be used since the private key is private to Cloudflare but the private key would actually be needed in your own server.

Comment: Thank you, this confirms it for me.  I wanted to check because I had someone tell me that you could use Cloudflare Origin certs.  But that didn't really make sense to me.